# Advantages of anonymous mmap over malloc under memory pressure

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

I am running some large array processing code (on a Pentium running Linux). The sizes of the arrays are large enough for the processes to swap. So far it is working, probably because i try to keep my read and writes contiguous. However, I will soon need to handle larger arrays. In this scenario, would switching over to anonymous mmapped blocks help ?

If so would you please explain why.

In my shallow understanding, mmap implements a memory mapped file mounted from a tmpfs partition which under memory pressure would fall back to the swapping mechanism. What I would like to understand is how does mmap do it better than the standard malloc (for the sake or argument I am assuming that it is indeed better, I do not know if it is so).

Note: Please do not suggest getting a 64 bit and more RAM. That, unfortunately, is not an option.

Comment: I suggest switching to... ah nevermind. Just wait for the cat to bark. Also, profile, profile, profile. I don't anticipate there would be any difference, but depending on your usage patterns, there might be.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat The mmaped interface is unimplemented. Before implementing it I want to know if there is a realistic chance of it doing better and why

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The memory that backs your `malloc()` allocations is handled by the kernel in much the same way as the memory that backs private anonymous mappings created with `mmap()`.  In fact, for large allocations `malloc()` will create an anonymous mapping with `mmap()` to back it anyway, so you are unlikely to see much difference by explicitly using `mmap()` yourself.

At the end of the day, if your working set exceeds the physical memory size then you will need to use swap, and whether you use anonymous mappings created with `mmap()` or `malloc()` is not going to change that.  The best thing you can do is to try and refactor your algorithm so that it has good [locality of reference](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/l.html#locality.of.reference), which will reduce the extent to which swap hurts you.

You can also try to give the kernel some hints about your usage of the memory with the `madvise()` system call.

Comment: Thanks, and am I correct to assume that kernel's swapping mechanism is better than mapping a disk based file.

Comment: @san: The mechanisms used by the kernel to write out dirty pages to a file-backed mapping or a swap-backed mapping are actually very closely related.  The advantage of using a file-backed mapping is that you can place the file on a device that you know is faster than swap.

Answer (score 2):

The key difference here is that with `malloc(3)`-ed input buffers you ask the kernel to *copy* the data from file-mapped pages that are already in memory, while with `mmap(2)` you just use those pages. The first approach doubles the amount of physical memory required to back up both  your and in-kernel buffers, while the second approach shares that physical memory and only increases number of virtual mappings for the useland process.

Comment: This is for memory-mapped files. The OP is specifically talking about anonymous mmaps, i.e. no backing file. There is no zero-copy path involved

Comment: Thanks. Is this the case when malloc internally uses a memory mapped file, or is it always the case for malloc ? I am not trained in CS so these may be very basic questions. And with anonymous mmap there is no on disk filemapping right ? Just that s region of RAM is given a file interface and that file interface is used for the file mapping.

Comment: Yes, I missed the 'anonymous' qualifier. See @caf's answer for that case. My answer applies for memory-mapping portions of the file.